# Is there a way to programmatically invoke an uninstaller in the control panel?

Tags: clickonce, uninstallation, controlpanel

I have developed an AddIn for Outlook, we didn't want to use VSTO, but did want to distribute/update it using ClickOnce.  So I built a ClickOnce app that is actually the installer/updater.  This of course necessitated a home-grown uninstaller as well.

All works as desired, except for one little rough spot: to fuly uninstall the app the user must run the uninstaller from the start menu *and* uninstall the installer/updater from the control panel.

It would be nice if I could launch that control panel uninstaller from my home-grown uninstaller's code.

TIA

Comment: Since it is your own program, you can detect it by whatever means you devise and execute the appropriate custom command line to uninstall it. No need to try to automate the control panel.

Comment: Yes we already do that, but I want to uninstall the ClickOnce app as well, and it seems the only way to do that is via the control panel.  The reason we occasionally need to do this is that the ClickOnce is hosted on multiple different (client-specific) web sites, including one for development/testing.  Once a user has installed from one site, he must uninstall before he can install the same app from another site.  It would be cleaner if it could be completely uninstalled in one step.

Comment: This question contains the answer to mine:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992379/uninstalling-a-clickonce-application-silently?rq=1][1]