# How full remove add-in Outlook programmatically?

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I need remove add-in Outlook programmatically.I remove the corresponding entry from the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins and HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins.Than Add-in dissappear from Outlook 
but in directory "C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\" remain dlls add-in and in windows menu "Remove and Update" so remain. Can I fully remove add-in?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you remove programs by simply running their uninstallers (add-remove programs panel does exactly that). You can find uninstaller command lines to run in the registry key [Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372105.aspx)

For programs installed via windows intaller (MSI) you can (actually, should) use Windows API to uninstall them, provided that you know what to uninstall. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523974/how-to-uninstall-msi-using-its-product-code-in-c-sharp)

If the add-in you are trying to uninstall was deployed via Click Once (looks like that), you can still use uninstall command line, but AFAIK there is no straight way to do that silently. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992379/uninstalling-a-clickonce-application-silently).