# Inno Setup uninstalling application installed without Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, inno-setup, rundll32

In my registry the UninstallString for the application has the value:

```
rundll32.exe dfshim.dll,ShArpMaintain 3sunptk.application, Culture=en-GB, PublicKeyToken=077ce3637efc8b1c, processorArchitecture=msil
```

In my 'Inno Setup' script in the Run section I have:

```
Filename: "rundll32.exe"; Parameters: "dfshim.dll,ShArpMaintain 3sunptk.application, Culture=en-GB, PublicKeyToken=077ce3637efc8b1c, processorArchitecture=msil,1"; StatusMsg: Uninstalling older version of Personal Timekeeping
```

However this doesn't remove the application, why?

The ,1 at the end of the parameters instructs the uninstall to run in silent mode which would seem to be the problem as this seems to cancel the install as this is the default button selected.  Removing ,1 and selecting the ok button fixes the problem.

So the question now is How do I uninstall in silent mode but selecting the Ok button by default?

Comment: [`People say`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4992379/960757) that there is no (reliable) way to silently uninstall a ClickOnce deployed application.

Comment: In the end I removed the ",1" at the end of the Parameters which made the uninstall visible and I was able to ensure it removed correctly.