# How to use /SILENT option in ShellExec() in inno setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, uninstallation, silent, silent-installer

I am uninstalling an App in my installer by using ShellExec. I want ShellExec() to work silently without user interaction .

Here is my code :

```
procedure UninstallMyApp;
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
  begin
    ShellExec('runas', 'rundll32.exe', 'dfshim.dll,ShArpMaintain MyApp.application, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=x86', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);                   
  end;
```

/S , /qn , /SILENT are used for silent installation but Here I am confused ,how to add /SILENT option in this code ?

Comment: @RobeN , i am not running it in command line . Eventhough there is SW_HIDE , it uses user interaction .

Comment: not exactly UAC popup , it just asks user whether to uninstall or not ? If user presses OK ,it will be uninstalled and if user presses CANCEL it will not uninstall .

Comment: @RobeN, it's not about rundll32. It's about what you pass to the `lpszCmdLine` parameter of the called dfshim.dll entry point. And if that (ClickOnce DLL) interface supports no such parameter, then you're out of luck. If you pass `SW_HIDE` to the `ShellExec` function, or to the `nCmdShow` parameter of the entry point, you'll just hide the problem, you'll hide the dialog asking the user to confirm. You either need to confirm that dialog, or better yet, find a parameter which performs a silent uninstall, which, as the [`people say`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4992379/960757) does not exist.

Comment: Since I dont know much about C# ,can any one tell me ,what this options mean  ('dfshim.dll,ShArpMaintain MyApp.application, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=x86', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode) ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with C#. It literally means that through the rundll32.exe Windows application you are executing a ClickOnce DLL's (dfshim.dll) function `ShArpMaintain` and you are passing to it command `MyApp.application, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=x86`. And that function `ShArpMaintain` itself must have a support for silent uninstall, otherwise you'll be only hiding the confirmation dialog. You need to tell that function "hey, do not show that dialog, just uninstall what I want", but that's what it's missing (most probably).

Comment: As a bonus, that `ShArpMaintain` function is not officially described anywhere, so what is passed there as parameters is most probably just a result of someone who disassembed its code.